# Handle local notification without launching app

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

Is there any way to create an action for local notification that does something without launching the IOS application? 
For example, I need to send notification's alertBody via SMS or Email not launching the App or keeping it in the background

UPD

I want to show activityViewController's view while the App is inactive

Here is my code

```
class MyClass {
  class func SendTxt(text: String) {

    if let topVc = getTopMostController() {

        let objectsToShare: [AnyObject] = [ text ]
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = topVc.view 

        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypePostToFacebook ]

        topVc.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }
}

//AppDelegate

func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification, completionHandler: () -> Void) {

    print("handleActionWithIdentifier = \(identifier)")

    if application.applicationState == .Background ||  application.applicationState == .Inactive {

        if identifier == "send" {
            MyClass.SendTxt("Hello world")
        }
    }
    completionHandler()
}
```

Comment: `UIUserNotificationAction` has an `activationMode` property that you set to foreground or background

Comment: @dan, in this case the App starts running in the background mode and activity view controller for sharing is not visible until I open the App. Is there way to show activity view controller while the App is in the background?

Comment: Updated: added code sample

Comment: You can't show a view controller when your app is in the background